# Proof this integral is equal to this sum: $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^x-x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I was able to determine the integral with trials and errors and we arrive with this sum, but was not able to proof it. So if anyone can proof it and also can offer a closed form.
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^x-x}dx\,=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^n}
$$

Comment: And I suppose you wrote $\Gamma$ instead of factorial as a hint of how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^x-x}dx &=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1-xe^{-x}}dx
\\\\&=\int_0^\infty \sum_{p=0}^\infty x^pe^{-(p+1)x}dx
\\\\&=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty x^pe^{-(p+1)x}dx
\\\\&=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{(p+1)^{p+1}}
\\\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^n}
\end{align}
$$ where we have used the classic eulerian integral,
$$
\int_0^\infty x^se^{-ax}dx=\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{a^{s+1}}, \quad a>0.
$$

Comment: Sorry i am new to this site and forgot to accept the answer. Your answer short and elegant (+1)